# R: Fill the area between multiple lines without clear maximum and minimum lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like the following. There are five different values of `x` (10,20,30,40,50) and four different values of `settings`.

```
 x                   settings   coherence_mean
10      alpha=0.05, beta=0.01        -119.1121
10       alpha=0.1, beta=0.01        -118.5555
10       alpha=0.05, beta=0.1        -119.3970
10        alpha=0.1, beta=0.1        -118.6293
20      alpha=0.05, beta=0.01        -127.0716
20       alpha=0.1, beta=0.01        -127.0320
```

I created a lineplot where the data is grouped by the `settings` column:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=t, y=coherence_mean, group = settings)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour=settings))
```

[image]

How do I fill area between the maximum and minimum of all the lines?

Comment: Create a new variable which looks at the four settings and takes the maximum value (and a second that takes the minimum value). Then use those two to create a `geom_ribbon()`

Comment: I have answered the question. In future, please make it easier to answer by including a useable version of the data in the post. To do this, you can copy and paste the output of the code `dput(df)` into the post

Comment: will do, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help: if you are happy with the answer please mark it as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Selina, did this solve your problem? Please mark the answer as accepted if it has :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way of doing this is to create a second dataframe which summarises the dataset.

Here is an example with a generic dataset:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(t = c(rep(10,4), rep(20,4), rep(30,4)), settings = rep(c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4"),3), mean = rnorm (12, 10))
```

This looks like:

```
    t settings      mean
1  10  Group 1  9.439524
2  10  Group 2  9.769823
3  10  Group 3 11.558708
4  10  Group 4 10.070508
5  20  Group 1 10.129288
6  20  Group 2 11.715065
7  20  Group 3 10.460916
8  20  Group 4  8.734939
9  30  Group 1  9.313147
10 30  Group 2  9.554338
11 30  Group 3 11.224082
12 30  Group 4 10.359814
```

The `aggregate` function can be used to summarise a list by groups:

```
# Find range
rangemin <- aggregate(df$mean, by = list(df$t), min)
rangemax <- aggregate(df$mean, by = list(df$t), max)
range <- merge(rangemin, rangemax, by = "Group.1")
names(range) <- c("Group", "min", "max")
```

Plotting the results.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_ribbon(data = range, aes(ymin = min, ymax = max, x = Group), fill = "skyblue2", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=t, y=mean, group = settings, colour=settings))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I felt this warranted another answer. The problem with the previous answer is that it didn't properly follow the lines. This is because it was taking the maximum value of the points at 10, 20 and 30. This meant that the formula wouldn't track lines if they intercepted each other midway.

In order to make a line which tracks the minimum value better, we need to interpolate the points:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)    

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(t = c(rep(10,4), rep(20,4), rep(30,4)), settings = rep(c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4"),3), mean = rnorm (12, 10))


# Creates a new, interpolated dataset
df_dt <- data.table(df)
df_dt_int <- df_dt[, approx(x = t,y = mean, xout=seq(from = 10, to = 30, by = 0.1)), by= settings]

# Calculates the range of the interpolated dataset
rangemin <- aggregate(df_dt_int$y, by = list(df_dt_int$x), min)
rangemax <- aggregate(df_dt_int$y, by = list(df_dt_int$x), max)
range <- merge(rangemin, rangemax, by = "Group.1")
names(range) <- c("Group", "min", "max")
range

ggplot() + 
  geom_ribbon(data = range, aes(ymin = min, ymax = max, x = Group), fill = "skyblue2", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=t, y=mean, group = settings, colour=settings))
```

[image]

As you can see, the line now properly follows the outside of the plot. As the plot interpolates, it will still be a chance there will be inaccuracies at the exact point where it crosses over. However this can largely be avoided by decreasing the step size of the approximation in `seq(from = 10, to = 30, by = *CHANGE THIS*)`